# Shiny input - Show all data if all is selected and plot summarize data

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am trying to filter a data frame from input. I want all data to show if the option All is selected. Here is what I have so far:

This will reproduce some data:

```
library(tidyverse)

lihn_service_line <- rep(c("Medical", "CVA"), 10)
dsch_date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2017/01/01"), to = as.Date("2018/08/01"), by = "month")
alos <- rnorm(20, mean = 6, sd = 0.5)
elos <- rnorm(20, mean = 5, sd = 1)
df_los <- data.frame(dsch_date, lihn_service_line, alos, elos)

df_los <- df_los %>%
  tibbletime::as_tbl_time(index = dsch_date) %>%
  tibbletime::collapse_by("monthly") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(dsch_date, add = T) %>%
  summarize(
    alos = round(mean(alos), 2)
    , elose = round(mean(elos), 2)
  )
```

The below is what I have so far:

````
Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Pick a Service Line.

```{r}

selectInput(
  "svcline"
  , label = h3("Service Line")
  , choices = c(
    "All"
    , "Medical"
    , "GI Hemorrhage"
    , "COPD"
    , "CVA"
    , "CHF"
  )
  , selected = "Medical"
)

```


Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### ALOS vs. ELOS

```{r}

svc_line <- reactive({as.character(input$svcline)})

alos <- reactive(
  {
    df_los %>%
      filter(svc_line == "All" | lihn_service_line == svc_line) %>%
      collapse_by("monthly") %>%
      group_by(dsch_date, add = T) %>%
      summarize(
        alos = round(mean(los), 2)
        , elos = round(mean(performance), 2)
      )
  }
)

renderPlot(
  {
    # alos <- df_los %>%
    #   collapse_by("monthly") %>%
    #   group_by(dsch_date, add = T) %>%
    #   summarize(
    #     alos = round(mean(los), 2)
    #     , elos = round(mean(performance), 2)
    #     ) %>%
    #   select(dsch_date, alos, elos)

    alos() %>%
      ggplot(
        mapping = aes(
          x = dsch_date
          , y = alos
          )
        ) +
      geom_line(
        color = "black"
        ) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line(
        aes(
          x = dsch_date
          , y = elos
          )
        , color = "red"
        ) +
      geom_point(
        x = alos$dsch_date
        , y = alos$elos
        , color = "red"
        ) +
      labs(
        x = ""
        , y = "ALOS"
        , caption = "Black Line is Actual and Red Line is Benchmark"
        )  +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0)
        ) +
      scale_x_date(
        breaks = alos$dsch_date
        , labels = date_format("%b %Y")
      )
    }
)

```
````

So I am attempting to take input and filter a data.frame and have the corresponding graph(s) update. The error I get is the following:

I get the following warning/error:

```
Warning: Error in ==: comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
  203: filter_impl
  202: filter.tbl_df
  196: function_list[[i]]
  195: freduce
  194: _fseq
  193: eval
  192: eval
  190: %>%
  189: <reactive> [<text>#29]
  187: .func
  184: contextFunc
  183: env$runWith
  176: ctx$run
  175: self$.updateValue
  173: alos
  169: renderPlot [<text>#51]
  167: func
  127: drawPlot
  113: <reactive:plotObj>
   97: drawReactive
   84: origRenderFunc
   83: output$out7e92cd2b0c4de4e1
    3: <Anonymous>
    1: rmarkdown::run
```

Comment: `"All" != "all"` (check your case). BTW, you can reduce your code significantly by using just the `else` block, changing filter to `filter(input$svc_line == "All" | lihn_service_line == input$svc_line)`.

Comment: If you define alos as an reactive you need to call it with brackets `alos() %>% ggplot(...`.

Comment: @TimTeaFan found the immediate bug, I found one you hadn't seen yet :-)

Comment: Thank you both, I now get an error of `ERROR: argument is of zero length`

Comment: Use  `print(alos())` in you `renderPlot` to print your reactive dataframe to the console - this will help you debugging. If you want, show us your data or at least the `head()` of it with `dput()`.

Comment: nothing prints out

Comment: So it is probably empty.

Comment: yet if I run `df_los %>% filter(lihn_service_line == "CVA") %>% head()` for example I get the rows back I expect

Comment: `filter(lihn_service_line %in% input$svc_line)`  should be the correct way to filter. Printing not only the reactive dataframe but also your filter input$svc_line to the console will help debugging.

Comment: I change to that and still get a zero length error very strange to me

Comment: I usually put the if statement inside the dplyr::filter. When „All“ is selected filter a condition which is always true.

Comment: can you show example? I seem to not be able to get it.

Comment: There is no need for `if` within `filter`, my first comment provided the functionality with `input$svc_line == "All" | lihn_service_line == input$svc_line`. There should be no need for `%in%`, unless you use `selectInput(..., multiple=TRUE)`.

Comment: MCP_infiltrator, I can generally get the select/plot functionality to work (using `mtcars` since we don't have sample data), including the `filter` stuff, so it is likely that the problem is beyond `filter` in your dplyr pipe. I can only guess what `collapse_by` is or does, so I don't know where the problem definitely resides. It could help immensely if you made it more reproducible (perhaps reproducing your issues with `mtcars` or similar) and reduce the code (I think just `ggplot(...)+geom_point()` might suffice for proof-of-concept).

Comment: I will work on it. collapse_by is from tibbletime I think a zoo wrapper

Comment: added code to generate sample data

Comment: Good luck, MCP, I have no experience with `tibbletime` so would likely just get in the way. I hope you'll be able to find your culprit elsewhere in the code ... I suspect it has nothing to do with shiny/rmarkdown.

Comment: Than you, me too

Comment: @r2evans: You are correct, `filter(lihn_service_line %in% input$svc_line)` makes only sense when there are multiple inputs. And your way of filtering without an if-statement is quite handy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example using the iris dataset. Below I add an example with the data you provided. There were several mistakes in the call to ggplot as well as in creating the df_los data. Let me know whether this approach works on your real data.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---


Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Pick a Species

```{r echo = FALSE} 

selectInput(
  "species",
    label = h3("Species"),
    choices = c("All",unique(as.character(iris$Species))),
   selected = "All"
)

```


Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  ### Data & Graph 

```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE} 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris_reac <- reactive({

    iris %>% 
    # this is the filter method r2evans suggested below I commented my own longer filter version out
    filter(input$species == "All" | Species == input$species) 
    # filter(if (input$species != "All") Species == input$species else 1>0) %>% 
    summarise(sepal_length = mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm = T),
              sepal_width = mean(Sepal.Width, na.rm = T),
              petal_length = mean(Petal.Length, na.rm = T),
              petal_width = mean(Petal.Width, na.rm = T)) %>% 
    gather(key = metric) 

})

renderPlot({

    print(iris_reac())

    ggplot(iris_reac(), aes(x = metric, y = value)) +
       geom_col(width = 0.5)

})

```
````

## Update

The approch below uses your example data.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---


Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  Pick a Species

```{r echo = FALSE} 

selectInput(
  "svc_line",
  label = h3("Service Line"),
   choices = c(
    "All",
    "Medical",
    "GI Hemorrhage",
    "COPD",
    "CVA",
    "CHF"
  ),
  selected = "Medical"
)

```


Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  ### Data & Graph 

```{r echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE} 
library(tidyverse)
library(tibbletime)

lihn_service_line <- rep(c("Medical", "CVA"), 10)
dsch_date <- seq.Date(as.Date("2017/01/01"), to = as.Date("2018/08/01"), by = "month")
alos <- rnorm(20, mean = 6, sd = 0.5)
elos <- rnorm(20, mean = 5, sd = 1)
df_los <- data.frame(dsch_date, lihn_service_line, alos, elos)

df_los <- df_los %>%
  tibbletime::as_tbl_time(index = dsch_date) 

alos_data <- reactive(
  {
    df_los %>%
      filter(input$svc_line == "All" | lihn_service_line == input$svc_line) %>%
      collapse_by("monthly") %>%
      group_by(dsch_date, add = T) %>%
      summarize(
        alos = round(mean(alos), 2)
        , elos = round(mean(elos), 2)
      )
  }
)


renderPlot({

    print(alos_data())

    alos_data() %>%
      ggplot(
        mapping = aes(
          x = dsch_date
          , y = alos
          )
        ) +
      geom_line(
        color = "black"
        )  +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line(
        aes(
          x = dsch_date
          , y = elos
          )
        , color = "red"
        ) +
      geom_point(aes(
        x = dsch_date
        , y = elos)
        , color = "red"
        )  +
      labs(
        x = ""
        , y = "ALOS"
        , caption = "Black Line is Actual and Red Line is Benchmark"
        )  +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 0)
        ) +
      scale_x_date(
        date_breaks = "1 month"
        , date_labels = "%b %Y"
      )



})

```
````